# ok my car will turn over but not crank its 2005 nissan altima 2.5 4 calender we changed crank position sensor spark plugs and coil pack

Tags: fuel-system, nissan, cranks-wont-run, altima

I have a 2005 model nissan altima 4 cylender2.5. My car will turn over just won't crank we have replaced a crank position sensor changed coil pack and spark plugs it just won't crank checked fuel pump and filter both seem to be fine

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: How many miles on vehicle?  When was the last time the car was running?

Comment: What was the symptom before you performed the repairs? Or is this a new problem since the repair? Put a timing light on a plug wire and see if it fires when cranking. State the result. You can put the timing light on the low-side of the coil if there is no high tension cable. (The timing lights I used could pickup the 12 volts on the low side and fire the light. They were Mac and Snapon timing lights).